# Webpack: Is there a way to replace imported file path before processing?

Tags: css, webpack

Setup: react, webpack, regular css and style loaders, nothing fancy

I want to be able to replace imported file on build step. Like if I build app with env `WITH_THEME=true` replace one css file with another with different name.

For example, I have 2 css files, `style.css` and `style.theme.css`, in react component I import only one file like this `import './style.css'` (I don't want to change this line, I know it is possible to make `if` condition with env var here).

So, if I start webpack with `WITH_THEME=true` I want it to actually import `style.theme.css` instead of regular `style.css`, **but only if** `style.theme.css` exists.

I came up with this solution, it is test condition for loader:

```
  // ...
  test: filePath => {
    if (!/\.(s*)css$/.test(path.extname(filePath))) {
      return false;
    }

    const { dir, name, ext } = path.parse(filePath);
    const themeFilePath = `${dir}/${name}.theme${ext}`;

    if (WITH_THEME && fs.existsSync(themeFilePath)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
  // ...
```

But with this way I need to import both `style.css` and `style.theme.css` in the component, so webpack could exlude one of them. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe there are some post-css solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've actually ended up with:

I made webpack alias for `theme-config` file, which I import in every `.(s)css` file (`@import '~scss-config';`).

```
    resolve: {
      // ...

      alias: {
        'scss-config': path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          `./src/styles/config-${env.THEME || 'default'}.scss`
        )
      }
    },
```

It allows to have multiple theme files, but you only need to import single config file, which got replaced with needed theme file in build step.